# An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.While running update migrations in having this error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
>   H Result=0x8013193C
>   Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
>   Stack Trace:
>   <Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
>   Inner Exception 1:
>   SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.AccessoryAdmins'.`

Comment: This looks like dbo.AccessoryAdmins entity is not available in the database so its throwing this error. If the entity is there and still you are getting error then read this, it may help you to resolve - https://ardalis.com/entity-framework-invalid-object-name-dbo-albums

Comment: dbo.AccessoryAdmins is either no longer available in the entity context